# C# Parallel copy - Issue with Small size files

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have a C# Azure function to read a file content from Blob and write it to a Azure Data Lake destination. The code works perfectly fine with the large size files (~8 MB and above) but with the small size files the destination file is written with 0 bytes. I tried to change the chunk size to a lower number and parallel threads to 1 but the behavior remains the same. I am simulating the code from Visual Studio 2017.

Please find the code snippet I am using. I have gone through the documentation on Parallel.ForEach limitations but didn't come across anything specific with the file size issues. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/potential-pitfalls-in-data-and-task-parallelism)

```
        int bufferLength = 1 * 1024 * 1024;//1 MB chunk
        long blobRemainingLength = blob.Properties.Length;
        var outPutStream = new MemoryStream();
        Queue<KeyValuePair<long, long>> queues = new 
                                             Queue<KeyValuePair<long, long>>();

        long offset = 0;
        while (blobRemainingLength > 0)
        {
            long chunkLength = (long)Math.Min(bufferLength, blobRemainingLength);
            queues.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<long, long>(offset, chunkLength));
            offset += chunkLength;
            blobRemainingLength -= chunkLength;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Queues: " + queues.Count);

        Parallel.ForEach(queues,
              new ParallelOptions()
               {
                //Gets or sets the maximum number of concurrent tasks
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10
               }, (queue) =>
                  {
                   using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                      blob.DownloadRangeToStreamAsync(ms, queue.Key, 
                                    queue.Value).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                      lock (mystream)
                        {

                          var bytes = ms.ToArray();
                          Console.WriteLine("Processing on thread {0}", 
                           Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                           mystream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                        }

                }
             });
```

Appreciate all the help!!

Comment: Your writes to `mystream` will occur in a indeterminate order. Can you explain exactly what problem you are trying to solve with this code? As far as I can tell, `using(var blobStream=blob.OpenRead(...)){await blobStream.CopyToAsync(mystream);}` is all you need to do. Why all the complexity? Multi-threaded writing to the same stream is a broken idea.

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve with the parallelization is Azure Function time out of 10 minutes. The idea is to read the chunks of data from Blob Storage and write to Azure Data Lake. Assuming the idea is broken, I don't understand the reason why the issue happens only with the small size files and even with a single thread (MaxDegreeofParallelism = 1). Can you eloborate your code? Do mean read the blob storage and write it to ADL using the same stream?

Comment: If I run the following code `Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0,10),i=>Console.WriteLine(i))`, the order is indeterminate. Unless I'm mistaken, your code suffers from the same problem. Each iteration of the loop racing to the lock where you perform your writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue with my code. The ADL Stream writer is not flushed and disposed properly. After adding the necessary code, parallelization with small/large files works fine.

Thanks for the suggestions!!

Comment: feel free to accept your own answer as an answer for the question.